# How to see the pdf file contents before creating the pdf file using mpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, mpdf

Link to my JsFiddle (**[Desired Output](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmednawazbutt/ukvn4fxe/3/)**)

**Target**:
The HTML I get there is exactly what I need in my PDF but when I try to generate a PDF using mPdf library in my codeigniter controller, the [Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5MZrZEwuinuQKWVCs-J3g6fZ6MOxMSJ/view?usp=sharing) looks terrible.

**Problem**:
I want to find a way to debug what is getting inside this PDF file and what is causing the output to go wrong. I want to see the generated HTML inside the PDF before it turns out to become a file.

**My PHP code to create a PDF**:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$style1 = file_get_contents(base_url('public/admin/css/formstyles.css')); // external css
$style2 = file_get_contents(base_url('public/admin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
$mpdf->WriteHTML($style1,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($style2,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data['template'],\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
// I want to check the TOBE PDF output so that I can see what is wrong with my content here
$mpdf->Output($path.$company_id.'/'.$template_id.'.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE); // opens in browser
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If i can understand you then you can do it as following ( i've checked with this way):

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$style1 = file_get_contents(base_url('public/admin/css/formstyles.css')); // external css
$style2 = file_get_contents(base_url('public/admin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
$mpdf->WriteHTML($style1,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($style2,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data['template'],\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);

// capture the output into buffer
ob_start();
$mpdf->Output($path.$company_id.'/'.$template_id.'.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE); // opens in browser

// holds the buffer into a variable
$html = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_get_clean();

// creates a html file with contents at root
file_put_contents('htmlFile.html', $html);
```

And, If you want to see the output on browser of the pdf without creating a file then you've to use the below code:

```
$mpdf->Output($path.$company_id.'/'.$template_id.'.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE); // Sends output inline to browser
```

Or you can also use

```
$mpdf->Output($path.$company_id.'/'.$template_id.'.pdf', "I"); // Sends output inline to browser
```

So whenever you change anything of the pdf file's code, just refresh the generated pdf in browser, you'll see the changes.

You can get more idea about output patterns of mpdf from here https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html

Comment: the output it gives is a PDF string. I need to see HTML so I can  debug it

Comment: my traget is to check the contents before it turns into PDF

Comment: I have visited the link. Its of no help in this context. But thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Ok, i got you and i've updated my answer. please check if it works for you.

Comment: this creates an HTML file but its empty

Comment: I have tried different combinations of your code. nothing shows anything in $html in file. File is empty and has no content at all

Comment: I guess the only way to see the output of PDF is by creating for for every little test